# awstats doesn't create data files with site domain name in them

Tags: awstats

I'm trying to get awstats installed on a new server and I can get it to generate the data files, but they're all labels as awstatsMMYYYY.txt instead of awstats.example.com.MMMMYY.txt. If I rename them after they're created, they show up correctly in the web interface. I'm using awstats 7.1. I'm invoking it using the following:

```
./awstats.pl -config=example.com -debug=5
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Awstats - 7.0 (build 1.976) - Perl /usr/bin/perl 5.012003
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - DIR=. PROG=awstats Extension=pl
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - QUERY_STRING=config=example.com&amp;debug=5
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - HTMLOutput=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - YearRequired=2012, MonthRequired=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - DayRequired=, HourRequired=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - UpdateFor=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - PluginMode=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - DirConfig=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - Opened config: ./awstats.example.com.conf
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Config file read was "./awstats.example.com.conf" (level 1)
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Search an available language among HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 -  No language defined or available. Will use Lang=en
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Check_Config
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogFile='/srv/www/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/apache2/example.log* |'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogType='W'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogFormat='1'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogSeparator=' '
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DNSLookup='1'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirData='/srv/awstats-data'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirCgi='/cgi-bin'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirIcons='/icon'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  NotPageList css,bmp,png,ico,swf,xml,js,jpg,jpeg,rss,class,gif
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  ValidHTTPCodes 304,200
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  ValidSMTPCodes 1,250
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  UseFramesWhenCGI=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  BuildReportFormat=html
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  BuildHistoryFormat=text
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  URLWithQueryWithOnlyFollowingParameters=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  URLWithQueryWithoutFollowingParameters=
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Substitute_Tags on /srv/www/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/apache2/example.log* |
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogFile='/srv/www/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/apache2/example.log* |'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogFormat='1'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  LogSeparator=' '
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DNSLookup='1'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirData='/srv/awstats-data'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirCgi='/cgi-bin'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  DirIcons='/icon'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  SiteDomain='example.com'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MiscTrackerUrl='/js/awstats_misc_tracker.js'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{WormsShown}=5
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{ScreenSizesShown}=5
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{Domain}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{WindowSizesShown}=5
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{OsShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{PageShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{DownloadsShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{LoginShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{EMailsShown}=20
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{KeyphrasesShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{RefererShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{RobotShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{KeywordsShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{HostsShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MaxNbOf{BrowsersShown}=10
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Robot}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Worm}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{ScreenSize}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Browser}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Domain}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Os}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{EMail}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Login}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Refer}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Keyphrase}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{WindowSize}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{File}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Keyword}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Host}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 -  MinHit{Downloads}=1
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - FrameName=main
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Language_Data [FileLang="./lang/awstats-en.txt"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data with files to load: search_engines.pm,operating_systems.pm,robots.pm,browsers.pm,mime.pm
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data [FilePath{search_engines.pm}="./lib/search_engines.pm"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data [FilePath{operating_systems.pm}="./lib/operating_systems.pm"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data [FilePath{robots.pm}="./lib/robots.pm"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data [FilePath{browsers.pm}="./lib/browsers.pm"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Ref_Data [FilePath{mime.pm}="./lib/mime.pm"]
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Read_Plugins with list: 
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Scan for last history files into DirData='/srv/awstats-data' with mask='(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)'
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Last year=0 - Last month=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Last day=0 - Last hour=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - LastLine=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - LastLineNumber=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - LastLineOffset=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - LastLineChecksum=0
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 1 - Call to Init_HashArray
Wed Oct 17 22:50:53 2012 - DEBUG 2 - UpdateStats is 1
Create/Update database for config "./awstats.example.com.conf" by AWStats version 7.0 (build 1.976)
From data in log file "/srv/www/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/apache2/example.log* |"...
```

And my config file looks like this:

```
LogFile="/srv/www/awstats/tools/logresolvemerge.pl /var/log/apache2/example.log* |"
LogType=W
LogFormat=1
LogSeparator=" "
SiteDomain="example.com"
HostAliases="www.example.com example.com localhost 127.0.0.1 REGEX[example\.com$]"
DNSLookup=1
DirData="/srv/awstats-data"
DirCgi="/cgi-bin"
DirIcons="/icon"
AllowToUpdateStatsFromBrowser=0
AllowFullYearView=2
EnableLockForUpdate=0
DNSStaticCacheFile="dnscache.txt"
DNSLastUpdateCacheFile="dnscachelastupdate.txt"
SkipDNSLookupFor=""
AllowAccessFromWebToAuthenticatedUsersOnly=0
AllowAccessFromWebToFollowingAuthenticatedUsers=""
AllowAccessFromWebToFollowingIPAddresses=""
CreateDirDataIfNotExists=0
BuildHistoryFormat=text
BuildReportFormat=html
SaveDatabaseFilesWithPermissionsForEveryone=0
PurgeLogFile=0
ArchiveLogRecords=0
KeepBackupOfHistoricFiles=0
DefaultFile="index.php index.html"
SkipHosts=""
SkipUserAgents=""
SkipFiles=""
SkipReferrersBlackList=""
OnlyHosts=""
OnlyUserAgents=""
OnlyUsers=""
OnlyFiles=""
NotPageList="css js class gif jpg jpeg png bmp ico rss xml swf"
ValidHTTPCodes="200 304"
ValidSMTPCodes="1 250"
AuthenticatedUsersNotCaseSensitive=0
URLNotCaseSensitive=0
URLWithAnchor=0
URLQuerySeparators="?;"
URLWithQuery=0
URLWithQueryWithOnlyFollowingParameters=""
URLWithQueryWithoutFollowingParameters=""
URLReferrerWithQuery=0
WarningMessages=1
ErrorMessages=""
DebugMessages=1
NbOfLinesForCorruptedLog=50
WrapperScript=""
DecodeUA=0
MiscTrackerUrl="/js/awstats_misc_tracker.js"
UseFramesWhenCGI=1
DetailedReportsOnNewWindows=1
Expires=0
MaxRowsInHTMLOutput=1000
Lang="auto"
DirLang="./lang"
ShowMenu=1                  
ShowSummary=UVPHB
ShowMonthStats=UVPHB
ShowDaysOfMonthStats=VPHB
ShowDaysOfWeekStats=PHB
ShowHoursStats=PHB
ShowDomainsStats=PHB
ShowHostsStats=PHBL
ShowAuthenticatedUsers=0
ShowRobotsStats=HBL
ShowWormsStats=0
ShowEMailSenders=0
ShowEMailReceivers=0
ShowSessionsStats=1
ShowPagesStats=PBEX
ShowFileTypesStats=HB
ShowFileSizesStats=0    
ShowDownloadsStats=HB   
ShowOSStats=1
ShowBrowsersStats=1
ShowScreenSizeStats=0
ShowOriginStats=PH
ShowKeyphrasesStats=1
ShowKeywordsStats=1
ShowMiscStats=a
ShowHTTPErrorsStats=1
ShowSMTPErrorsStats=0
ShowClusterStats=0
AddDataArrayMonthStats=1
AddDataArrayShowDaysOfMonthStats=1
AddDataArrayShowDaysOfWeekStats=1
AddDataArrayShowHoursStats=1
IncludeInternalLinksInOriginSection=0
MaxNbOfDomain = 10
MinHitDomain  = 1
MaxNbOfHostsShown = 10
MinHitHost    = 1
MaxNbOfLoginShown = 10
MinHitLogin   = 1
MaxNbOfRobotShown = 10
MinHitRobot   = 1
MaxNbOfDownloadsShown = 10
MinHitDownloads = 1
MaxNbOfPageShown = 10
MinHitFile    = 1
MaxNbOfOsShown = 10
MinHitOs      = 1
MaxNbOfBrowsersShown = 10
MinHitBrowser = 1
MaxNbOfScreenSizesShown = 5
MinHitScreenSize = 1
MaxNbOfWindowSizesShown = 5
MinHitWindowSize = 1
MaxNbOfRefererShown = 10
MinHitRefer   = 1
MaxNbOfKeyphrasesShown = 10
MinHitKeyphrase = 1
MaxNbOfKeywordsShown = 10
MinHitKeyword = 1
MaxNbOfEMailsShown = 20
MinHitEMail   = 1
FirstDayOfWeek=1
ShowFlagLinks=""
ShowLinksOnUrl=1
UseHTTPSLinkForUrl=""
MaxLengthOfShownURL=64
HTMLHeadSection=""
HTMLEndSection=""
MetaRobot=0
Logo="awstats_logo6.png"
LogoLink="http://www.awstats.org"
BarWidth   = 260
BarHeight  = 90
StyleSheet=""
ExtraTrackedRowsLimit=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I didn't realized I had downloaded awstats beta (7.1). Stable (7.0) works, so this is probably just a bug.